# Converting enum type to a specific, predefined array of hex values in C++

Tags: c++, enums, c-strings

What would be the most optimal and shortest way to write a function returning an array of 8-bit hex values, which are assigned based on an enumerated parameter.

I need to hard code commands, which will be sent over bluetooth and still have an easy access to them in code. So I have an enum with all possible commands listed in a human-readable way.

```
enum eventType {
    MODIFY_A,
    MODIFY_B,
    MODIFY_C,
    MODIFY_D
}
```

The communication protocol I try to adapt uses custom packets with predefined hex values. So for example, sending `0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03` could change led colour of a receiving device.

The library used for ble communication accepts arrays of said hexes, or other words, just a plain C string.

It would be easiest to simply define an array in a switch() after declaring it, just like this:

```
uint8_t* getCommandOf(eventType event) {
    uint8_t command[4];
     
    switch(event) {
        case eventType::MODIFY_A:
            command = {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; break; 
        case eventType::MODIFY_B:
            command = {0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; break; 
        case eventType::MODIFY_C:
            command = {0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; break; 
        case eventType::MODIFY_D:
            command = {0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; break; 
    }

    return command;
}
```

Then I could simply call:
`sendOverBLE(getCommandOf(eventType::MODIFY_A));`

Unfortunately, we can't do that in C++.
I'm open to suggestions. How would you solve it? I though of a few solutions, butI don't like any of them.

Maybe define them in a 2d array? Or a custom container class?

Comment: Just assign the values to the members of the enum.

Comment: Return `std::array` by value or make a `static const` array inside the function.

Comment: @Taekahn Ok, but how would I do so in C++? I know I can do that with an individual hex. But a single command consists of many hexes. I can't just write MODIFY_A = {0x00, 0x01...}

Comment: It will depend on if your target system is little or big endian, but just assign its its value. i.e. `MODIFY_A  = 0x000001`; You can then later read that as raw bytes `uint8_t *` or memcpy it where you need it. `OTHER_COMMAND = 0x76ADBEEF`

Comment: OK, thanks. I would like to keep the original formatting though for the sake of readability. That's the whole problem. I know I could write 0x0100 instead of 0x01 0x00. But then It would become unreadable. Some of those commands are quite lengthy and consist of many '0's. So instead of simply changing the seventh byte from 0x01 to 0x00 I would have to count and find the 14th '0' in a line and change it to '1'.

Comment: C++ has allowed digit separators since C++11 or 14 IIRC. i.e. you can write `0x00'00'01`

Comment: OK, didn't know that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Btw, your function returns the address of an array that is on the local stack of the function, so it's out of scope on the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using and returning a [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).  That would change your function to

```
std::array<uint8_t, 4> getCommandOf(eventType event) {
    switch(event) {
        case eventType::MODIFY_A:
            return {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        case eventType::MODIFY_B:
            return {0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        case eventType::MODIFY_C:
            return {0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        case eventType::MODIFY_D:
            return {0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; 
    }
    // for bad input
    return {}; // for all zeros
    // or use an exception
    throw std::invalid_argument("some error message here");
}
```

If you need to pass this array to a function that takes a `uint8_t*`, then you can use `array`'s `data` member to get such a pointer like

```
my_uint8_t_ptr_func(getCommandOf(eventType::MODIFY_A).data());
```

Comment: It's better to use `static_assert` instead of `return {};`/`throw ...`

Comment: @Genjutsu `static_assertt` only works at compile time, and this function can be called at run time

Comment: Either add new element into enum: `enum MyEnum { first, second, ..., size}` and do `static_assert(MyEnum::last ==42)` or add new constexpr variable near the enum declaration and do `static_assert(MyEnumSize == 42)`

Comment: @Genjutsu You can cast a value to an enum, as long as the enum's underlying type can represent that value, and it's well defined behavior. Someone could call for example `getCommandOf(static_cast<eventType>(12345))`. It isn't sufficient to be sure that all `enum` constants are covered by the `switch`, the function could still be the source of UB otherwise.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You and I must really think alike. I was just writing the exact same comment and I even used the value 12345 :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not only it should represent that value, but also be in range of the original enum. E.g. `enum MyEnum : int32_t { first = 42, second = 1337}` can only represent values between 42 and 1337. Most enums, however, are as simple as in the author's post so this `static_assert` is helpful in such cases.

Comment: @Genjutsu Being limited to a range between enum values would be surprising to me. Can you please cite or link a source so I can read about it?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#10

Comment: @Genjutsu Thanks for the link. It looks like you are right if the underlying type is unspecified. So you are right that the restriction applies to the question's case. But in the example you provided in the comments, it would not apply since the underlying type is specified. Edit : I would consider the runtime check and the `static_assert` to check for different errors, I don't think either replaces the other.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yeah, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: *I even used the value 12345 :)* That's amazing! I've got the same combination on my luggage!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in complete control over your `enum` you could define it as follows:

```
enum eventType : uint8_t {
    MODIFY_A = 1,
    MODIFY_B,
    MODIFY_C,
    MODIFY_D
}
```

Then your function could be:

```
std::array<uint8_t, 4> getCommandOf(eventType event) {
    return { event, 0, 0, 0 };
}
```